# Acumatica "Unable determine proper company id for the request"

Tags: acumatica

I'm working on writing an integration to Acumatica's contract based API and I am having issues preventing me from getting data from the API.  Here is the error:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException
>
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
> process request. ---> PX.Data.PXUndefinedCompanyException: Unable
> determine proper company id for the request.

Here is my API integration code which lives inside one of my API controller methods:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{

    var binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding()
    {
        AllowCookies = true
    };

    var address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://acumaticasandbox.mydomain.com/MyCompany/entity/Default/5.30.001");

    using (DefaultSoapClient client = new DefaultSoapClient(binding, address))
    {
        client.Login("myuser", "mypassword", "MyCompany", null, null);

        Entity[] items = client.GetList(new SalesOrder(), false);

        client.Logout();

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, items);
    }
}
```

Obviously "mydomain" and "MyCompany" are real values in my actual code.

I can't seem to get past the client.Login call no matter what I've tried.  Any advice is appreciated.

I am using Acumatica endpoint version 5.30.001 and using C# for the integration code.

Comment: From your code I think your code if for an Acumatica of version 5.30, but exactly which one is it?

Comment: Yes I'm using 5.30.001.  I've updated the question with this as well.  Thanks

Comment: I am not asking for the endpoint version but the version if the acumatica instance on which you are making your integration which can be found at the bottom of the login screen

Comment: @samol518, ok it says it's version 5.30.2489 on the login screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the 'company name' in your request, use the company 'login name'.
You can find the company login name in System->Management->Explore->Companies

Comment: I think this may have been it.  I had the wrong company name (there was an extra space).  It's now telling me invalid credentials.  Do I use the same credentials I'm using to login to the Acumatica Cloud ERP application?  Or are there separate credentials for the company that I'm using.

Comment: or I could just try putting in the correct password :)  it worked.  Thanks!